# How to add parent fieldname to newly added row in json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have below code using which am able to push new row into my json object, but couldn't add parent fieldname like (d0,d1,d2.. ) into the newly added row, how can i do it?

**Code:**

```
    var d = [{
        "id": 0,
            "name": "Housing",
            "value": 71
    }, {
        "id": 1,
            "name": "Travel",
            "value": 85
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "name": "Restaurant",
            "value": 44
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "name": "Bank",
            "value": 33
    }];

    var dataset = {};
    d.forEach(function (e, i) {
        dataset['d' + i] = e;
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(dataset,null,2));
    var input='Banking';

    var dataset_final={};

    d.forEach(function (e, i) {
      counter=i;
      });
      alert(counter+1);
    var input='Movies';

    d.push({id:counter+1,name:input,value:"3"});
    alert(JSON.stringify(d,null,2))
```

I would like to push data into 'dataset' variable directly. How can add parent field name like 'd4' for 4th row which will be newly added for the name: Movies ?

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_panduga/hx6tyjvp/17/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var counter = Object.keys(dataset).length;
dataset['d' + counter] = {name: 'Banking', value: 100};
```

Comment: Thanks Hunan, I will do it this way :)